# Non-static data members class deduction

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to solve type deduction issue.

Here's the demo code, that uses function overloading to define, whether the passed variable is int or double

```cpp
std::string tcast( const double &x){ return "Floating Point";};
std::string tcast( const int    &x){ return "Integer";};

int main(){
    double dA;
    int    iB;
    std::cout << "Access to variable type \n";
    std::cout << "dA : "<< tcast( dA )<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "iB : "<< tcast( iB )<< std::endl;
}
```

```
Access to variable type 
dA : Floating Point
iB : Integer
```

But this function doesn't work for non-static class members:

```cpp
struct Foo{
    double dA;
    int    iB;
};

int main(){

    std::cout << "Member dA : "<< tprint( &Foo::dA )<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "Member iB : "<< tprint( &Foo::iB )<< std::endl;

}
```

GCC compilation error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:111:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘tcast(double Foo::*)’
  111 |     std::cout << "dA : "<< tcast( &Foo::dA )<< std::endl;
      |                                            ^
main.cpp:96:13: note: candidate: ‘std::string tcast(const double&)’
   96 | std::string tcast( const double &x){ return "Floating Point";};
      |             ^~~~~
main.cpp:96:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘double Foo::*’ to ‘const double&’
   96 | std::string tcast( const double &x){ return "Floating Point";};
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
main.cpp:97:13: note: candidate: ‘std::string tcast(const int&)’
   97 | std::string tcast( const int    &x){ return "Integer";};
      |             ^~~~~
main.cpp:97:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘double Foo::*’ to ‘const int&’
   97 | std::string tcast( const int    &x){ return "Integer";};
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

But the following code compiles :

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::string tprint( const T    &x){ return typeid(x).name();};
...
std::cout << "dA : "<< tprint( dA )<< std::endl;
std::cout << "iB : "<< tprint( iB )<< std::endl;
std::cout << "Member dA : "<< tprint( &Foo::dA )<< std::endl;
std::cout << "Member iB : "<< tprint( &Foo::iB )<< std::endl;
```

And so it's visible for compiler that dA has type double and iB int

```
dA : d
iB : i
Member dA : M3Food  // ends in d
Member iB : M3Fooi  // ends in i
```

So what should be the right way to deduct the type of the non-static data member?

Comment: You are passing pointer to member, not `double` or `int`. What do you want to deduce?

Comment: Have you looked at `is_integral` and `is_floating_point` in the type_traits library?
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits

Comment: Type of `&Foo::dA` is `double Foo::*`.

Comment: [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) seems more appropriate than function overload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [*template argument deduction*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) to our advantage here. Pointer to member data's syntax is

```
DataType Class::*Pointer
```

After deducing the member type we can call the required overload.

```
template<typename Class, typename MemType>
std::string tcast(MemType Class::*mData){
    return tcast(MemType{});
}
```

[Link to the code in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PKj4a8K7q)

Answer (score 2):

You might add extra overload:

```
template <typename C>
std::string tprint(double C::*){ return "member Floating Point";};

template <typename C>
std::string tprint(int C::*){ return "member Integer";};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b23d9dba5a816c9d)